# How to replace string by other file content in Makefile

Tags: regex, shell, makefile

I have a file with some `include` lines and I would like to read the filepath and replace this line with the file contents.

e.g. replace the line `<!-- include(path/filename.txt) -->` with content of `path/filename.txt`

```
# meta info
- a
- b

# included files
<!-- include(path/filename.txt) -->
```

My Makefile:

```
expand-includes:
    @echo "Expand all included file"
    perl -pi -e "s/<!--\s?include\((.+)\)\s?-->/`cat $$1`/" input.txt
```

The capture group looks get empty `$$1` and the script hangs.
Do I miss something?

Update:
Remove $(shell)

Comment: firstly, the recipe is run by shell anyway, so why do you need `$(shell ...)`?  secondly, `$1` is empty because the shell expands it because it's inside a double-quoted string (substituting the value of the first positional parameter, which is empty).  also, if I remember anything about Perl (which I don't necessarily, mind you), you want to use `\1` to refer to "the match register #1" -- ``cat $$1`` will substitute the contents of file named by `$1` (which, to repeat, is an empty string), not sure what's the idea there.

Comment: Why do you use `cat $$1` whereas with `-i` option in **Perl** modify in-place?

Comment: Thanks for @MichaelLivshin and @k-five. I would like to replace the string with corresponding file content so `-i` option is required. I tried for a while and find e modifier is exactly what I need. 

```perl -pi -e 's/<!--\s?include\((.+\.md)\)\s?-->/`cat $$1`/e' input.txt ```

Answer (score 0):

The following syntax works well.

`` perl -p -e 's/<!--\s?include\((.+)\)\s?-->/`cat $$1`/e' input.txt > output.txt ``